# Три инлайн-блока (элемента) и горизонтальное растягивание

Tags: css3, html, вёрстка, css

Есть заголовок такого типа: горизонтальная линия - текст - горизонтальная линия. Выглядит примерно вот так:

------ Заголовок ---------------------------------------------------

Т.е. первая линия фиксированного размера, затем идет текст заголовка на неопределенную ширину - в зависимости от длинны заголовка, затем идет линия, примыкающая к правой стороне заголовка и занимающая все оставшееся пространство на строке - т.е. тоже не определенного размера, как бы "резиновая". Помогите, пожалуйста идеями, как сверстать такой элемент! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Иногда можно обойтись одним блоком,
если задний фон, не текстура: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/nEu5E/

P.s> если честно голову сломал как сделать, если задний фон - текстура, получилось так: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/5BRtv/1/ но, уверен вариант так себе, может ещё кто что отпишет, самому интересно стало...

Comment: Хорошо! Скажите, а как бы ещё сделать так, чтобы при увеличении заголовка на две и более строки, линия выравнивалась по первой строке? Т.е.

----- Очень длинный заголовок.......... --
...продолжение длинного заголовка

Comment: @Олег Б, можно и [вот так][1] попробовать, правда у вас, по-моему, полегче будет)


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/FD5jb/

Answer (score 0):

@freeze, http://jsfiddle.net/FD5jb/2/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: url(http://www.dreamtemplate.com/dreamcodes/bg_images/light/l89.png);
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h2 span.h2sub {
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 33px;
  color: #00347E;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 9px 0px 15px 0px;
}
h2 span.h2sub span {
  width: 93px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #482d25;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12%;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
h2 span.h2sub span:first-child {
  left: -105px;
}
h2 span.h2sub span:last-child {
  right: -105px;
}
```

```html
<h2><span class="h2sub"><span>&nbsp;</span>Скажите, а как бы ещё сделать так, чтобы при увеличении заголовка на две и более строки, линия выравнивалась по первой строке<span>&nbsp;</span></span></h2>
```